# SQL Server 2008 Express - sample database download?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express

is there a sample database for SQL Server 2008 that I can download to practice learning how to develop/use SQL Server...I have downloaded the SQL Server 2008 Express Edition, Visual Studio 2008, MS Web Dev 2008, ASP.NET 3.5.....

...don't think I can download anything else before I start learning how to use this stuff.

Thanks guys...

p.s. rookie coming from ms access/vba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Adventure Works](http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTDBProdSamples) is the new sample databases for the SQL 2008 database. If you're using the express version you might want to look into downloading the Adventure Works LT version, it has many fewer tables than the full blown Adventure Works database.

You can also always use the [northwind and pubs](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06616212-0356-46A0-8DA2-EEBC53A68034&displaylang=en) databases that were used with the old SQL 2000 databases. Those are still used for many examples and demos.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: so i can still use the old 2000 nw&p database with 2008 express edition? thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can just run the scripts that come with the installation and you will have the northwind or pubs database created and filled.

Comment: so i downloaded that and tried to attach the database in the sql server management studio, and i got an error. so how do i install it? or add the database files to sql server?

Comment: i also tried to just click through the install which open sms automatically with the script, but then freezes up right away

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTDBProdSamples

It has a lot of community and Microsoft driven sample databases.  Determine what you want to learn, and then download the appropriate database sample.